# Fetch the path of the file I just clicked to open with a java application (jar executable)

Tags: java, windows

I have this simple program that does nothing:

```
class ShowTheNameOfTheFile{
  static public void main(String[] argv){

  }
}
```

I compile it as ShowTheNameOfTheFile.jar and configure my Windows machine to open all txt files with it.

Now, when I click a txt file it will open my ShowTheNameOfTheFile.jar program.

In java, how can I know with txt file has opened the ShowTheNameOfTheFile application?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Thanks. Is it clearer?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov and now?

Comment: yes, now I understand what you mean.

Comment: Isn't the filename handed over to the java program as a parameter (`argv`)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254123/open-with-a-java-program

Comment: it should be `String` not `string`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043029/utilising-a-file-association-in-a-java-application

Comment: @Andy argv was what I did in the first place

Comment: "Under windows, you need to attach some details into the registry". And that's why it wasn't working. Thank you all:

Comment: from your link (stackoverflow.com/questions/12254123/open-with-a-java-program).
I don't how to put url in comments.
If you post an answer with it I will gladly give you the creadits:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line arguments should give the file paths.

```
class ShowTheNameOfTheFile{
    static public void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(argv));
    }
}
```

Comment: "Under windows, you need to attach some details into the registry". And that's why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the code by Joop Eggen.

The thing is that if it is the only code and you assign this jar to Windows Open with it might just silently die without printing any output to any console, because it is not started from a console.

First, try from console

```
java -jar ShowTheNameOfTheFile.jar 1 2 3
```

if number gets printed then it works okay.

Then add something like this

```
Process Builder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "echo", args[0]);
pb.start();
```

to your code and then double click a file.